# Error in Database While using Code-First based approach in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework Code-First approach to create database. The database was fine previously but now although I have not changed anything in model it shows me this error:

> The model backing the 'MyDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Then I found that using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` in `DbContext` would solve this error, and it did.

But currently I am getting another error like this:

> Cannot drop database "MyDb" because it is currently in use.

What should I do now?

Comment: Close all tab windows into SSMS or tabs in Visual Studio that are currently showing some tables data.

Comment: @CodeNotFound i closed all the tabs but still it shows same error while running the project.

Comment: Restart SQL Server this will close all connections. If that not solve your issu then just drop the database via SSMS :-)

Comment: Do you really want to drop your database? Or do you just want to update the schema, that it fits to your models?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I restarted sql server but still this didn't fix the issue. I only want to update the schema that fits my model..

Comment: Yes, delete the database in SQL Server Management Studio. If as I suspect you can't, then you have something else going on. Eventually you will want to use [migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) to update your database so it does not get dropped on every model change.

Comment: thanks i used migration, and the problem was solved...